# How to Fix:Though favicons are added, it doesn't show in Google Search

Tags: seo, html, meta-tags

First of all , it does show up in the browser tab.But when I search in google the favicon doesn't show next to the url.
[image: Like this]

This is what's on the html

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/img/favicon/apple-icon-57x57.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/img/favicon/apple-icon-60x60.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/img/favicon/apple-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/img/favicon/apple-icon-76x76.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/img/favicon/apple-icon-114x114.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/img/favicon/apple-icon-120x120.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/img/favicon/apple-icon-144x144.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/img/favicon/apple-icon-152x152.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/img/favicon/apple-icon-180x180.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192"  href="/android-icon-192x192.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/img/favicon/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="/img/favicon/favicon-96x96.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/img/favicon/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/img/favicon/favicon.ico">
<link rel="manifest" href="/img/favicon/manifest.json">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/img/favicon/ms-icon-144x144.png">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#f7961e">
<meta name="msapplication-navbutton-color" content="#f7961e">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
```

How can I make the favicon appear in google search ?
I haven't typed anything in robots.txt and I asked google to index my site multiple but nothing happend.

Thanks in advance.